# Material UI Autocomplete: Rendering inside custom Menu dropdown looses focus

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So I took the example react-mui has in the docs about having the autocomplete inside a custom popover [demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/s3gj2?file=/demo.js:3921-4069), but I replaced the popover with the Menu component because the popover gets cropped inside modals.

So the minimal code is something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-x9rcg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

The problem I'm experiencing is that if you write something inside the input box, then use the **arrow keys for selecting an item, the input box gets blurred** and so the autocomplete **resets** it. this behavior doesn't happen when using a popover.

Any suggestion on how to keep the input focused even when selecting an item using the keyboard arrow keys?

Comment: I would go into resolving cropping issue rather then change the STABLE default behavior of 3rd party component from lib like Material UI